# MANIFEST.MF file for JAR Used in Web App?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, classpath, manifest

I've developed a utility library that will be used in many of our enterprise Java applications.  This library has numerous additional dependencies that also need to be on the classpath.  I'd like to avoid forcing our developers to add a zillion entries to their MANIFEST.MF files, and let them instead just include my library.  Is there any way that my library's MANIFEST.MF file can reference its dependencies and have them picked up by the enterprise applications that will be using my library?

I've tried referencing them in my library's MANIFEST.MF file using the full path to the dependencies on the filesystem.  That didn't work.  I end up with ClassNotFoundException errors for all of my dependencies.  Is there something else I should be trying?

Comment: What is your app server? Shared library solutions are likely to be container-dependent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a web application, you'd normally put it in a WAR file. The idea is that you bundle the required dependencies in that WAR file, by adding the jars to the /WEB-INF/lib folder inside the WAR. Web containers (like in a Java EE application server) know of this structure and will include those jars on the classpath.

If your library has additional dependencies, just tell the users about it and either redistribute them with your library if the license allows it, or tell them where to obtain them. When using a decent tool for creating a web app like an IDE, Ant with Ivy, or Maven (or a combination of these), then handling and bundling dependencies should be no problem.

Comment: Agreed...  In a perfect world.  However, we're a large enterprise and our shared services/libraries are developed by different teams.  We store these libraries in a central system so that bugfixes, updates, etc. can be picked up without having to repackage a WAR file.  As a result, we make use of MANIFEST.MF files to reference these files.  I'd prefer not to require all of the web developers that will be using my library to add the dozen or so JAR files that my library depends on to their MANIFEST.MF files as well.

Comment: But if you replace a jar with a newer version, you'd have to restart or at least redeploy the web app anyway to load in the altered classes, I think. I do believe having read something about GlassFish allowing you to redeploy only parts of an app, like separate classes or maybe even lib files.

Answer (score 0):

I've done this with a number of tools. It is a truly horrible hack but seems to work reliably.

- Give them a special manifest to use. Something like:

  Manifest-Version: 1.0
  Main-Class: com.xxx.yyy.zzz.YourSpecialClassThatHacksTheClassPath
  Real-Main-Class: com.ppp.qqq.TheirMainClass
- In your special class, screw around with the classpath (not easy), read the manifest "Real-Main-Class" entry (a bit easier) and launch their main from that (not really difficult at all).

Obviously this will not work with a .war file.

Comment: If it does not work with a WAR file then it does not help my use case.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, this works so long as you stick to the format **very carefully**, i.e. stick to **exactly two spaces** before each "file:" etc:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: package.TestClass
Class-Path:  file:/D:/WebServer/Tomcat/shared/lib/BlueCove.jar
  file:/D:/WebServer/Tomcat/shared/lib/classes12.jar
  file:/D:/WebServer/Tomcat/shared/lib/comm.jar
  file:/D:/WebServer/Tomcat/shared/lib/FTP.jar
  file:/D:/WebServer/Tomcat/shared/lib/FTP2.jar
  file:/D:/WebServer/Tomcat/shared/lib/iText.jar
  file:/D:/WebServer/Tomcat/shared/lib/j2ee.jar
  file:/D:/WebServer/Tomcat/shared/lib/jmxremote.jar
  file:/D:/WebServer/Tomcat/shared/lib/jmxri.jar
  file:/D:/WebServer/Tomcat/shared/lib/jmxtools.jar
  file:/D:/WebServer/Tomcat/shared/lib/jpos15.jar
  file:/D:/WebServer/Tomcat/shared/lib/js.jar
  file:/D:/WebServer/Tomcat/shared/lib/mail.jar
...
  file:/C:/WebServer/Tomcat/shared/lib/soap.jar
  file:/C:/WebServer/Tomcat/shared/lib/sqljdbc.jar
  file:/C:/WebServer/Tomcat/shared/lib/tools.jar
```

Comment: Do the classpath entries use some syntax of their own? Because if they're URIs, I think it'd need to start with `file:///D:...`

Comment: @G_H: All I know is that this format works for me. If this format does not work for you, by all means try something else.

Answer (score 0):

Even I had the same problem.  As mentioned above, the solution was to have exact two space after file:/ and one space after .jar file and at the end, press enter key.

I know this is not a neat solution, but it works.  enjoy.